# when i run the python django services in local machine by ip address,it is not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I try first: $ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Then, $ python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.48:8000

Then also didn't get the access.It getting only access when open in browser localhost:8000.Can help to solve this issue

```
 $ python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: First thing to try: use `0.0.0.0` instead of a fixed IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You should try first: `$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Then, `$ python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.48:8000`

You want to access the page locally only from the server side.

```
$ python manage.py runserver 8000
```

open a browser and check: `http://localhost:8000` or `http://192.168.1.48:8000`

Comment: Currently  I have checked this two urls,but unfortunately i got the same response "the site cannot be reached".Support me to resolve this issue.